# how to change the diameter of bubble chart in d3

Tags: d3.js

How I will update the diameter in a bubble chart [like this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269).  For dynamic data, I want to update diameter.  As I increase the number of nodes the diameter should be increased and as I decrease the number of nodes the diameter should be decreased.

Comment: Which diameter?  The entire packed layout or each individual circle?

Comment: entire packed layout. in the mentioned example it is "diameter = 960"